# ¿Cómo obtener resultado ejecución de una INSERT con Doctrine QueryBuilder?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Estoy usando la clase `Doctrine\DBAL\Query\QueryBuilder` para ejecutar ***INSERT*** en  MySQL.
Los registros se están creando pero no se como obtener ese resultado de "éxito" de la ejecución.

**SQL tabla:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS foods (
  id bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(60) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  active tinyint(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  created_at timestamp NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
  updated_at timestamp NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
  deleted_at timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  UNIQUE KEY foods_name_unique (name)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

**Código:**

```
// $arrConnectionParams: [host, db_user, password, ...]

// Doctrine\DBAL\Connection
// Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager
$connection = DriverManager::getConnection($arrConnectionParams);

// Doctrine\DBAL\Query\QueryBuilder
$queryBuilder = $connection->createQueryBuilder();
$queryBuilder
    ->insert('foods');
    ->setValue('name', '?')
    ->setParameter(1, 'Loncha queso');

// Doctrine\DBAL\Result
$result = $queryBuilder->executeQuery();
```

He probado a extraer el resultado con:

```
$result->fetchOne();            // false
$result->fetchNumeric();        // false
$result->fetchAssociative();    // false
$result->fetchFirstColumn();    // []
$result->fetchAllAssociative(); // []
```

Esperaba recibir un *true*, 1, un array o un objecto con el registro creado.

Estoy usando ["doctrine/dbal" versión 3.8.0](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal.git)
y PHP 8.3.2.

Comment: Todos los métodos que estás intentando son para consultas `SELECT`, para encontrar el total de filas afectadas en consultas del tipo `INSERT`, `UPDATE` o `DELETE` debes usar [`rowCount()`](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/a9cd978f2fc4b983c2acdcd3f783ee0959e86508/src/Driver/Result.php#L77), o sea: **`$result->rowCount();`** Es cierto que se agradecería una mención de eso en la doc, pues brilla por su ausencia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Todos los métodos que estás intentando son para consultas `SELECT`, para encontrar el total de filas afectadas en consultas del tipo `INSERT`, `UPDATE` o `DELETE` debes usar [`rowCount()`](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/a9cd978f2fc4b983c2acdcd3f783ee0959e86508/src/Driver/Result.php#L77), o sea: **`$result->rowCount();`** Es cierto que se agradecería una mención de eso en la doc, pues brilla por su ausencia.

La llamada a `$result->rowCount();` te devolverá el total de filas afectadas, único criterio válido para determinar si una consulta `INSERT`, `UPDATE` o `DELETE` **ocurrió realmente**. Es decir, si no hay al menos una fila afectada, esa consulta no tuvo éxito ninguno, aunque estuviera escrita correctamente desde el punto de vista sintáctico, pues esas consultas pueden fallar por problemas de duplicidad, porque no existían filas que cumpliesen los criterios, etc.

Comment: Perfecto, `rowCount` es justo lo que buscaba. Ya lo había intentado probar sobre la conexión. Muchas gracias.

Comment: @Orici `rowCount()` es un método propio de la clase `Result`, como pudiste ver en el enlace. Aunque la conexión también te devuelve el total de filas afectadas si usas [`executeStatement()`](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/a9cd978f2fc4b983c2acdcd3f783ee0959e86508/src/Connection.php#L1188).